# JFileChooser, полное удаление All Files

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте!

Цель: в окошке JFileChooser'a, в меню  "Files of type:" сделать так, чтобы был только один единственный, не изменяемый формат.

Пункт All Files убрал (`fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false)`), теперь вместо All Files - пустота. И 2-й по списку - уже мой формат.

[image]

Как сделать так, чтобы по-дефолту был мой формат и его нельзя было изменить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внимательно это читаем [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html),
после чего обращаем особое внимание на создание своего собственного FileFilter.

Comment: собственный FileFilter есть

все оказалось очень просто
fileChooser.setFileFilter(ff);

Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.